# How to convert the selected data into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

[In this example](https://www.kaggle.com/code/spiceluke/spice-xyz-ethereum-blocks), stream_reader.read_pandas() selects data from all the columns from the table. I want to convert the selected data into a pandas data frame. How can I do that? I am adding the [google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lXuMwkoI7uvE7b12langQZmurWtJxQ48?usp=sharing) as well for your reference.

Comment: ??? I'm not sure how you missed this, but `stream_reader.read_pandas()` returns a pandas DatafFame.  That is it's job.  No conversion is necessary.

Comment: @TimRoberts When we are printing 

print(stream_reader.read_pandas()) , 

then the data is not pretty as is generally in a pandas data frame.

If we write 

a = stream_reader.read_pandas()
a

It is printing only the column names.

Answer (score 1):

Just run `stream_reader.read_pandas()` without `print()` and you'll get what you're looking for out of the colab notebook.

[image: colab screenshot]

Comment: Yes, it worked. But when I am trying to do something like https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lXuMwkoI7uvE7b12langQZmurWtJxQ48?usp=sharing

as shown in the last line, it is just printing the headings.

Comment: I appears that `stream_reader.read_pandas()` empties the stream after the first time it is called. Directly run `a=stream_reader.read_pandas()` after you do the `spice.query()` and then run a cell with just `a` afterwards.

Comment: Aka, If you run `stream_reader.read_pandas()` twice, only the first will have content.